# SQL query to append data to the existing value of a cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a query which would append data to the existing value of a cell. 
For Eg:
Current Value of Cell: "2013-03-15" 
Value after Update: "2013-03-15,2013-03-25"

Is it even possible? 
Note: i do not want to update the entire column at once. Only cell.

Comment: can you give sample record?

Comment: What is the data type of that column. Why do you want to do that? If you are trying to add multiple values for that column, please **Don't do that**. Better of add a new column or a new table.

Comment: @user2063626 I cant use that, since i dont want to calculate date i want to append already existing data. Which includes "," (comma) as well.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal , it is varchar. I am adding the dates on which a student was absent in a particular month in this column.

Comment: @Arbaaz - In this case, don't do that, it is really bad. Add a new tale `StudentAbsence`: `StudentId` Foreign key to the student table then the `AbsenceDate` of data type `date` or datetime not varchar. In this column `AbsenceDate` add multiple rows for each `studentid` as a new row, this will make your work later on much more easier and your tables will be [**normailezed**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal You are right, my way is the bad way to do it. But i you must understand you have '28,201' reputation whereas i am at '73' lol but i am DEFINITELY going to try to normalize my table more. Even though it increases complexity a bit(for me).

Comment: @Arbaaz - This won't increase complexity, How would you got the students that were absent in a specific date? this for example will be more complex, but using a basically normailzed table it will be a simple select where statement, also you won't grantee the dates to be in a valid date format, because of the varchar column.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal have a look at this table ..
http://snag.gy/oLKCd.jpg   I am using this table for assigning timetable to teachers and also for their attendance, should i remove absent column from there and replace it with absentid or something and create another table 'teacherabsence' with foreign key absentid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE tblMyTable
    SET MyCell = MyCell + ',' + 'My Other Value'
```

Or

```
UPDATE tblMyTable
    SET MyCell = MyCell + ',' + @MyParameter
```

Bear in mind, the type of `MyCell` will need to be text based, for instance: `nvarchar(256)` etc...

Answer (score 1):

If assuming you are using DateTime DataType, then you must:

Create another table, for example RequestDateTime:

```
Create table REQUEST_DATE_TIME(
  REQUEST_ID VARCHAR(10), -- or whatever PK your main table use
  Request_date DATETIME
)
```

Then add relation between the two tables.

However when you use varchar(n) data type, you can do a simple as:

```
Update table set DateTimeCell = DateTimeCell + CAST(@VALUE AS VARCHAR)
```

Maybe you can get better answer if you tell what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible if you are using Date. Use Text data type.

First, read the data from database of a corresponding cell and then append your data by String concatenation.

Next, Update the cell

```
while (myReader.Read())
{ 
String d1=myReader["dat"].ToString());
}
String d2=d1+","+your_variable or data
```

The update it

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do like that**. Create another column, like newDate and store your new value there. When you use dates you have to store them, like dates, not like text. Or you can store your dates in single column with some kind on foreign key to you referenced table of students.